# Getting the desired datetime value from x axis in bokeh

Tags: python, datetime, bokeh

I have read the documentation and have searched Google and StackOverflow for answers but none the wiser yet.

I have a bokeh graph with circle glyphs for two variables 'score' and 'stress', and a third variable 'date' as a datetime x axis (picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYgKY.png)). I want the users to be able to click on the circles and be taken to a URL showing a detailed view of that particular data point which is identified by its corresponding date.

I have enabled a tap tool with openURL callback which appends the datetime value at the end of the URL. The problem is that once a data point is clicked, the datetime value passed is not in the desired format: **`'2016-07-20'`**. What I get instead is the following value: '1468969200000'. So, the user gets re-directed to 'url/1468969200000/' instead of 'url/2016-07-20/'.

Is there a way to change the format of the date value that gets passed once a data point is clicked?

Here is my code (run in jupyter notebook):

```
import datetime
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import Range1d, OpenURL, TapTool, HoverTool, ColumnDataSource, DatetimeTickFormatter

data = {'score': [4.33, 2.66, 4.66, 2.66, 2.66, 1.66, 1.0, 4.33], 
        'stress': [3.66, 3.0, 3.0, 1.33, 3.66, 3.33, 1.0, 4.33], 
        'date': [
            datetime.date(2016, 7, 17), 
            datetime.date(2016, 7, 18), 
            datetime.date(2016, 7, 19), 
            datetime.date(2016, 7, 20), 
            datetime.date(2016, 7, 21), 
            datetime.date(2016, 7, 22), 
            datetime.date(2016, 7, 23), 
            datetime.date(2016, 7, 24)
        ]
       }

source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

TOOLS = ['hover', 'pan', 'tap']

plot = figure(x_axis_type='datetime', plot_height=250, tools=TOOLS)

plot.circle('date', 'score', legend='score', size=15, color='red', source=source)
plot.circle('date', 'stress', legend='stress', size=10, color='orange', source=source)
plot.y_range = Range1d(1, 5, bounds=(1,5))
plot.x_range = Range1d(datetime.date(2016, 7, 17), datetime.date(2016, 7, 23))

hover = plot.select(type=HoverTool)
hover.tooltips = [
    ("score", "@score"),
    ("stress", "@stress"),
    ("date", "@date")
    ]

url = 'url/@date/'
taptool = plot.select(type=TapTool)
taptool.callback = OpenURL(url=url)

show(plot)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to directly parse the datetime in numeric format? I am having the same issue using CrosshairTool and a datetime axis where the workaround in the answer below is not applicable.

Comment: The solution suggested by jlarsch worked for me at the time. I haven't worked with Pandas since then so haven't encountered this problem again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple workaround would be to provide date in string format in addition.

```
dateStr= {'dateStr': [x.isoformat() for x in data['date']]}
data.update(dateStr)
```

then, you can use dateStr in your hover.tooltips and to generate the url

```
hover.tooltips = [
    ("score", "@score"),
    ("stress", "@stress"),
    ("date", "@dateStr")
    ]

url = 'url/@dateStr/'
```